# How to copy between variant of type and variant of type pointer

Tags: c++, stl, std-variant

So I have two variants (I have shortened them, they have more types):

```
std::variant<int *, double *> PtrVariant;
std::variant<int, double> ValueVariant;
```

I want to copy value between them.

This does not work:

```
ValueVariant = *PtrVariant;
```

This works:

```
if (std::holds_alternative<int>(ValueVariant))
  ValueVariant = *std::get<int *>(PtrVariant);
else if (std::holds_alternative<double>(ValueVariant))
  ValueVariant = *std::get<double *>(PtrVariant);
```

Is there a way to copy values between them without checking what type is held by variant?

Comment: You probably should check `PtrVariant` type, and not `ValueVariant`...

Comment: @Jarod42 They have both been initialized, so they match, but you are right.

Comment: `ValueVariant = ` reset its type, so old type is not important. (contrary to `PtrVariant` where you retrieve by type).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to do the dispatch:

```
std::visit([&](auto* p){ ValueVariant = *p; }, PtrVariant);
```